# What is causing the fatal error: SimpleITK.h: No such file or directory? (C++ project with cmake)

Tags: c++, cmake, simpleitk

I get `fatal error: SimpleITK.h: No such file or directory` after executing make -j8 trying to build my project.

I have no expirience with SimpleITK. Here are the steps that followed to install SimpleITK:

I downloaded the source code of SimpleITK using git:

```
git clone https://github.com/SimpleITK/SimpleITK.git
```

After downloading SimpleITK’s source code i executed the following commands in the parent of the SimpleITK source directory to configure the SuperBuild:

```
mkdir SimpleITK-build
cd SimpleITK-build
cmake ../SimpleITK/SuperBuild
```

After that  I used `make -j8` to build SimpleITK.

I have set the required CMake Variables ( **SimpleITK_DIR **and **ITK_DIR **) in the SimpleITK-build/CMakeCache.txt like this (information taken from https://simpleitk.readthedocs.io/en/master/link_CppCMake_docs.html):

```
SimpleITK_DIR:PATH=/testproject/external/SimpleITK-build/SimpleITK-build
ITK_DIR:PATH=/testproject/external/SimpleITK-build/ITK-build
```

My C++ project structure:

```
 -testproject
 ---build
 ---exec
 ---external
 -----HighFive
 -----SimpleITK
 -----SimpleITK-build
 -----yaml-cpp
 ---include
 ---src
```

My CmakeLists.txt in the `testproject folder`:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.16)
set(CMAKE_CUDA_ARCHITECTURES 70)
project(
    project_name
    VERSION 0.1
    LANGUAGES CXX CUDA
)
find_package(Boost REQUIRED)
find_package(OpenCV REQUIRED)
find_package(SimpleITK)
include_directories( ${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS} )
add_subdirectory(external/HighFive-2.4.1)
add_subdirectory(external/yaml-cpp)
add_subdirectory(src)
add_subdirectory(exec)
```

and the second one in the `testproject/exec` folder

```
add_executable(vg vg.cpp)
target_compile_features(vg PUBLIC cxx_std_17)
target_link_libraries(vg PRIVATE loader_library renderer_library)
target_link_libraries (vg ${SimpleITK_LIBRARIES} )
```

I am really new to c++ and simpleitk. How can i fix this problem?
The project without simpleitk part has no issues.

Comment: Change `find_package(SimpleITK)` to `find_package(SimpleITK REQUIRED)` and make sure it does not complain.

Comment: you edited the cache file directly? Did you reconfigure after doing so? Usually you edit cache using commandline `-D`. If you edit cache directly, I'm pretty sure you need to run CMake configuration again to update the generated buildsystem.